# Visual Studio 2005 link error

Tags: .net, visual-c++

I am getting an linking error in Visual Studio 2005:

> mfcs80.lib(dllmodul.obj) : error LNK2005: _DllMain@12 already defined in MSVCRT.lib(dllmain.obj)

What could be the reason for this error?

" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"..\RtpDll\libs\Release" /LIBPATH:" packet.lib winmm.lib ws2_32.lib and other some project-dependent libraries.

Comment: another one for the crystal ball...

Comment: is mfc meant to link into clr apps??? Also, could you please provide some more info, like the project settings (particularly any you changed, and the original project template you used to create it).

Answer (score 0):

usually this type of error indicates that you are linking debugging code with release code which causes both crt libs (debug and release) te be linked in. Check if your program and all libraries are using either debug or release libraries.